# SSTP VPN on Windows Server 2016 works in LAN but not from WAN

Tags: windows, vpn, certificate-authority, windows-server-2016, sstp

I was setting up SSTP VPN on Windows Server 2016 at home using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NINcZ-2H2YY).

This works using a LAN client with Windows 10. The eventlog on the client shows:

> The user xxx has established a connection with VPN SSTP using the
>   device VPN4-1. (translated)

Using the same client via WAN (mobile connection / other location) I get the following message in the GUI:

> Can not connect to VPN SSTP. The remote connection was not established
>   due to VPN tunneling errors The VPN server may not be available. If an
>   L2TP / IPsec tunnel is used for the connection, the security
>   parameters required for IPsec negotiation may not be configured
>   properly.

In the eventlog I get:

> **A certificate chain was processed, but ended with a root certificate,
>   which is not considered trustworthy by the trust provider.**

As explained in the tutorial I added the certificate I got via http://SERVER/certsrv to the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities". How would you narrow down the error?

Comment: I'd like to help but I'm not going to watch a YouTube video to figure out what steps you took. Do you have any other guides you followed?

Comment: Most likely the issue is caused by an inability to download the CRL from outside of LAN network. Seems like your CRLs are not configured to be available from WAN.

Comment: And make sure if root certificate is installed in the machine store (not in current user store).